# Is there a way to write an interface using shorthand for properties with identital sub properties?

Tags: typescript

Looking to write this interface using shorthand for properties `Monday` to `Sunday` which have identical sub properties.

```js
interface Day {
  start: number
  end: number
}
interface Schedule {
  Monday: Day
  Tuesday: Day
  Wednesday: Day
  Thursday: Day
  Friday: Day
  Saturday: Day
  Sunday: Day
  closed: string[]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the common interface somewhere else like this:

```
interface DayDefinition {
  start: number;
  end: number;
}

interface Schedule {
  Monday: DayDefinition;
  Tuesday: DayDefinition;
  Wednesday: DayDefinition;
  Thursday: DayDefinition;
  Friday: DayDefinition;
  Saturday: DayDefinition;
  Sunday: DayDefinition;
  closed: string[]
}
```

Or if you want to shorten this even further: you can use a union to describe the possible days of the week:

```
interface DayDefinition {
  start: number;
  end: number;
}

type Day = 
  | 'Monday'
  | 'Tuesday'
  | 'Wednesday'
  | 'Thursday'
  | 'Friday'
  | 'Saturday'
  | 'Sunday';

type Schedule = {
  [K in Day]: DayDefinition;
} & { closed: Day[] };
```

Comment: Good point... is there a way to shorthand the keys `Monday` to `Sunday`  (updated the question as focus was on this aspect)?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Amazing! Thanks!